# 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' in JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.dll

Tags: c#, exception, resharper, xunit

When trying to run a very basic xunit test in debugging mode my test project throws several exceptions which seems to come from ReSharper.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Could not find file 'C:\Temp\test\TestProjekt\TestProjekt\bin\Debug\TestProjekt.xunit.runner.json'.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Could not find file 'C:\Temp\test\TestProjekt\TestProjekt\bin\Debug\xunit.runner.json'.

Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' 
The assembly named 'xunit.runner.utility.net452' was loaded from 'file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/Installations/ReSharperPlatformVs15_0a4dd3ad/xunit.runner.utility.net452.dll' using the LoadFrom context. The use of this context can result in unexpected behavior for serialization, casting and dependency resolution. In almost all cases, it is recommended that the LoadFrom context be avoided. This can be done by installing assemblies in the Global Assembly Cache or in the ApplicationBase directory and using Assembly.Load when explicitly loading assemblies.

testException thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in xunit.execution.desktop.dll
Thread was being aborted.

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in xunit.execution.desktop.dll
Thread was being aborted.

Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
Thread was being aborted.

Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Access to the path 'TestProjekt.PDB' is denied.

[...]

Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Access to the path 'TestProjekt.PDB' is denied.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' in JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.dll
Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

The program '[14628] JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[14628] JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What I have tried so far:

- Moved Project away from Default Profile Folder to c:\temp...
- Starting Visual Studio 2017 with local admin rights
- Updating ReSharper to the latest Version currently available (2018.2.1)
- Clearing ReSharper Cache
- Clean entire solution
- Create new empty class library Project and pull in xunit nuget packages afterwards (.NET Framework 4.7.2)
- Downgrading solution to .NET Framework 4.7
- Reinstall ReSharper and choose "Install for all users" instead of my user only, to ensure there are no left Overs in my Profile...

It seems that the same test project can be debugged without any issue on the Workstation of a Team mate... so there must be something wrong with my Installation.

What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: I seem to have hit the same problem. Did you find out any more?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling `Just my Code` in Visual Studio at least stops this first Chance exceptions from cluttering my Output. So thats Kind of a Workaround...